# combine 3 select statements and sort by timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I have 3 mysql statements each giving out different result set and I would like to represent all the results gathered from the queries sorted by timestamp desc in total .

For eg: if Purchased orders has timestamp before products then he items in purchased orders should be before products .
How do I do that and sent the combined sorted result of the 3 result set.I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from products order by timestamp desc ;");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows!=0)
{
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
}
echo json_encode($rows);

$query2=mysql_query("select * from user_purchased order by timestamp desc ;");
$numrows2 = mysql_num_rows($query2);
if ($numrows2!=0)
{
    $rows2 = array();
    while($r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
        $rows2[] = $2r;
    }
}
echo json_encode($rows2);

$query3=mysql_query("select * from delivery order by timestamp desc ;");
$numrows3 = mysql_num_rows($query3);
if ($numrows3!=0)
{
    $rows3 = array();
    while($r3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3)) {
        $rows3[] = $r3;
    }
}
echo json_encode($rows3);
```

Comment: "select * from products order by timestamp desc ;" semicolon inside ?

Comment: @M.chaudhry yes there is a semicolon inside

Comment: @M.chaudhry: `;` semicolon is legal inside quotes as stmt terminator.

Comment: @Ravinder how do I make the above requirement work  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine all the data and sort them by date descending, you would use a sub-query with `UNION ALL` and combine un-ordered results from all 3 tables...and then order the records by timestamp descending. Below is an example. However, if they all have different field names and the number of field names are different, you could create dummy field names to create consistent information. It's described below in an edit.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that all tables had the following structure

```
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id    | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| ts    | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

Let's look at the dummy data in each table.

**Products**

```
mysql> select * from products;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2014-03-26 04:39:06 |
|    4 | 2014-03-26 04:40:05 |
+------+---------------------+
```

**User_Purchased**

```
mysql> select * from user_purchased;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+
|    2 | 2014-03-26 04:39:19 |
|    5 | 2014-03-26 04:40:00 |
+------+---------------------+
```

**Delivery**

```
mysql> select * from delivery;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+
|    3 | 2014-03-26 04:39:28 |
|    6 | 2014-03-26 04:39:38 |
+------+---------------------+
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('host','usr','pwd');
mysqli_select_db($db,'yourdb');
$data = mysqli_query($db, "
    select * from
    (
        select 'products' as tbl, id, ts from products
        union all
        select 'purchased' as tbl, id, ts from user_purchased
        union all
        select 'delivered' as tbl, id, ts from delivery
    ) a
    order by ts desc
    "
);

echo "tablename\tid\ttime\n";
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "{$row['tbl']}\t{$row['id']}\t{$row['ts']}\n";
}
?>
```

**Output**

```
tablename       id      time
products        4       2014-03-26 04:40:05
purchased       5       2014-03-26 04:40:00
delivered       6       2014-03-26 04:39:38
delivered       3       2014-03-26 04:39:28
purchased       2       2014-03-26 04:39:19
products        1       2014-03-26 04:39:06
```

**Edit**

Let's say products table had fields id, productname, productnumber. 
Purchased had id, productid, purchasedate. 
Delivery had id, purchaseid, deliverydate.

You could combine all the fields in each query by doing something like and then sort on mytimestamp:

```
select 
    'products' as tbl, pdt_id, productname as pdt_productname, productnumber as pdt_productnumber,
    '-' as pur_id, '-' as pur_productid, '-' as pur_purchasedate,
    '-' as del_id, '-' as del_purchaseid, '-' as del_deliverydate,
    ts as mytimestamp
from products
union all
select 
    'purchased' as tbl, '-' as pdt_id, '-' as pdt_productname, '-' as pdt_productnumber, 
    id as pur_id, productid as pur_productid, purchasedate as pur_purchasedate,
    '-' as del_id, '-' as del_purchaseid, '-' as del_deliverydate,
    ts as mytimestamp
from purchased
union all
select 
    'delivered' as tbl, '-' as pdt_id, '-' as pdt_productname, '-' as pdt_productnumber, 
    '-' as pur_id, '-' as pur_productid, '-' as pur_purchasedate,
    id as del_id, purchaseid as del_purchaseid, deliverydate as del_deliverydate,
    ts as mytimestamp
from delivered
```

Comment: Best explanation ever.Thanks I will post any new query with regards to the question above here itself.I am accepting the answer for now.Thanks again.